# NHibernate manipulation query resulted in split queries

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have classes that implement the Interface `ILockable`.
Those classes are mapped with NHibernate on my database.

I want to update all objects of those classes that exist in the database and implement this interface.
Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
using (var session = SomeRandomMethodThatReturnsAHibernateSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
            {
                try
                {

                    session.Query<ILockable>()
                        .UpdateBuilder()
                        .Set(x => x.LockedBy, x => null)
                        .Set(x => x.LockedAt, x => null)
                        .Set(x => x.IsLocked, x => false)
                        .Update();

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
```

This code is working but NHibernate internally logs a warning:

```
11:13:32 WARN: manipulation query [UPDATE .Select[SomeRandomNamespace.ILockable,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey
Token=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[SomeRandomNamespace.ILockable], Quote((,
 ) => (new Dictionary`2(Equal(, NULL) ? 4 : 4, )LockedByNULLLockedAtNULLIsLockedFalse)), )] resulted in [28] split queries
```

Am I doing something "wrong" or not best practice like? How can I avoid this warning?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are creating a model object inheriting another model object , Hibernate got confused and resulted in multiple queries